# Total count in review stats

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, review-stats

The total count shown in the "[Your Review Stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/)" is not the actual total (screenshot attached). Looks like some review categories are not shown but counted in the total.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot from drupal.stackexchange.com]

Comment: I asked the same question, and when I noticed somebody else asked it already, I deleted mine. The second screenshot has been added from me. In my case, I edited 5 answers, and up-voted 5 answers; I didn't do anything else with the answers I reviewed clicking on "review answer," and the total is still not what I would expect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the total includes posts you reviewed, but didn't take any action on.

Comment: @lunboks In that case, the total should be higher than the sum of the single entries, which is not what happens in my case (the second screenshot).

Comment: @kiamlaluno I'm assuming those counters count your actions, and the total is the number of posts. You reviewed 8 posts. You upvoted some of them, you edited some of them, and in some cases you did both. If you downvote, edit, comment, and vote to close, that's 4 actions, but only 1 post.

Comment: @lunboks The problem is that I didn't up-vote and edit the same posts.

Comment: @kiamlaluno which site, I will look into it?

Comment: @waffles It is [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com). I am sure I didn't edit the same posts I up-voted because, when I saw the total was different from the one I was expecting, I tried editing some posts, and then up-voting other posts (after clicking "review answer"). As I understand, I could not have edited and voted the same posts, as once I review a post in that way, it vanishes from my list of posts to review.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is by-design.

You may have edited and upvoted the same post. The total is the **total number of posts** you reviewed.

Comment: I may add a tooltip to clear some of the confusion

Comment: You are correct that "The total is the total number of posts you reviewed." but something related that I mentioned in my question, "Looks like some review categories are not shown but counted in the total.". Regarding your point, "You may have edited and upvoted the same post", my count is actually greater rather than lesser (refer to first screenshot).

Comment: A post is reviewed as soon as you expand it, you need not take an action

Comment: Sounds good. So from your comments I understood the following: 1) "Total" is the total number of posts reviewed (meaning expanded the post even if no action is taken), 2) Counts displayed above the "Total" label are the actions that a user has performed on reviewed posts (its mathematical-total could be different from the total value given below).

Comment: Looks like "total" label has been rightly replaced with "reviewed" label.