# How does the calculation for Reviewer badge handle multiple actions on the same reviewed post?

Tags: discussion, review

I do a fair bit of reviewing. Now that the new Review Stats panel is shown on the review page (at least for some of us), I've noticed that doing two things to the same post (e.g. editing and upvoting) seems to count as two actions in the Review Stats.

Does this count as two actions for the purposes of the "200 actioned" criterion for the Reviewer badge? If so, then I'm not sure this is intended behaviour. If not, then the Review Stats might be misleading.

I get from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110711/total-count-in-review-stats) that the total row shows the total number of posts reviewed, but that isn't the same as the total number of posts *actioned* - thus the two criteria for the badge.

**EDIT** Per the discussion below, this means that the Review Stats are tracking only one part of progress to the badge. People will see their progress to the 1000-reviewed leg of the criteria for the Reviewer badge, but could be misled about their progress to the 200-actioned criterion.

Answer (score 3):

Taking two actions for the same post (e.g., down-voting a question, and then commenting on the down-vote) doesn't increment the number of actioned posts (which is not visible in the review statistics) by two because the post is only one.

Comment: Yes, but the Reviewed total includes posts you reviewed but didn't action. That is, it tracks your progress to 1000 reviewed posts, not to 200 actioned posts.

Comment: Still, down-voting a question, and commenting it doesn't count as 2 actioned posts, because the post is the same.

Comment: Reviewed != actioned.

Comment: I get that, but that means the Review Stats are not tracking number of actions for the purpose of the badge. (The "If not" case in my question.)

Comment: It means the review statistics are not showing you the number of the actioned posts. They show you the number of actions you took, and the number of reviewed posts, but not the number of the actioned posts.

Comment: Right, my point exactly. It means that people will see their progress to the 1000-reviewed leg of the criteria for the Reviewer badge, but could be misled about their progress to the 200-actioned criterion.